# ASP checkbox's 'checked' property always returns false

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, datalist

I had recently moved a "DataList"  control in to a UserControl and referenced it on my ASPX page. The DataList contains checkboxes with checked properties assigned by the data source initially.

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlspec" CssClass="specs" runat="server" GridLines="Vertical" OnItemDataBound="dlspec_ItemDataBound">
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
    <AlternatingItemStyle CssClass="alt-grey" />
    <SelectedItemStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
      <ItemTemplate>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td class="leftcol">
                 <asp:Label ID="lblDimension" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Dimension") %>'></asp:Label>:
               </td>
               <td class="ProductDetailData">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Attribute") %>'></asp:Label>
               </td>
               <td class="find-similar">
                 <asp:CheckBox ID="FindSimilarCheckbox" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("CheckBox")=="true"? true:false %>' Text='<%# Eval("AttributeID") %>' Visible='<%# Eval("CheckBoxState")=="0"? true:false %>' />
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
         </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:DataList>
```

Now, on a button click event in the "aspx" to which the user control is bound to, i try to get the "checked" properties of the check boxes to go through some logic.
I basically use the below to find the usercontrol and loop through the controls in it.

```
Control SpecsPanel = FindSimilarPnl.FindControl("Specifications").FindControl("dlspec");
foreach (Control ct in SpecsPanel.Controls)
        GetCheckedAttributes(ct, ref qry);
```

However the "checked' property of the checkboxes always comes out to be "false" after i moved the datalist in to the user control. Any ideas why? Am I missing something silly? Greatly appreciate any thoughts ideas. Let me know if I need to add more code for you to understand better.
Thanks

Comment: may I suggest something on how to find Controls in an easier fashion..?

Comment: Are you initializing the value to false somehow in your load event, without testing IsPostBack?

Comment: @DJKRAZE anything that is better than what I have is welcome. Thanks

Comment: @JonathanWood I wrapped the 'databind' events of the usercontrols within the !IspostBack condition

Comment: protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e) { if(!IsPostBack)
            {
                Pricing.DataBind();
                Specifications.DisplaySpecifications(_sri, IsMobilePage);
                availability.DisplayAvailability(_sri, IsMobilePage);
            }}

Comment: stick a breakpoint in the usercontrol code behind, see if its getting called and initialised again before the parent page event handler is being called...

Comment: this should givve you an idea of what you can do.. it should be pretty straigh forward..

Comment: @rocky The Page Load triggers, but not the data bind event since it is wrapped in (!ISPostBack). still getting the same error.

Comment: does that mean its datasource is empty then when it loads the control again? Hence all the false returns? Sorry just a shot in the dark, hard to tell without it infront of me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out why this is happening...going to answer my own question.
So the CheckBox ID in the template is "FindSimilarCheckBox" and it is renamed at data-bind time. so when the postback occurs, the server returns the ID's for all the checkboxes as "FindSimilarCheckBox" and Checked property for everything is false. I had to re-data bind the usercontrol and this time put in a condition to check if it is a postback operation and if the Check Box's Unique ID exists in the Request.Form collection in order to set the Checked property on the chkbox. Something like this :

```
protected void dlspec_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
 {
    var ck = e.Item.FindControl("FindSimilarCheckbox") as CheckBox;
            if (ck != null)
            {
                ck.ID = ck.Text;
                ck.Text = "";
                //EDIT: Karthik - Since we moved the Specifications in to user control, check if this a postback , then check to see the CheckBox state on the form while posting back
                if(IsPostBack && Request.Form[ck.UniqueID] != null)
                {
                    ck.Checked = true;
                }
 }
```

My issue is solved now. Hope this answer helps you understand what caused my issue. Let me know if i need to give more detail.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a Method you could create..

```
public void FindAllCheckedBoxes(Control ctrl) 
{ 
    if (ctrl != null) 
    { 
        foreach (Control c in ctrl.Controls) 
        { 
            if (c is CheckBox)
            {   
               ((CheckBox)c).Checked = false;
               //or mess around with the code to do what ever it is you want.. 
            } 
           //uncomment if you need to add recurisve call FindAllCheckedBoxes(c); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

usage: FindAllCheckedBoxes(FindSimilarCheckbox);

if you need to do this on a Web page you could use the following code as well 
make the changes necessary to fit your UseCase

```
Protected void SetCheckBoxState( ControlCollection  controls)
{
    Foreach (Control c in controls)
    {
        If (c is System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox)//change to make it CheckBox
        {
            CheckBox cb = c as CheckBox;
            cb.Checked = false; // or true what ever you need to do 
        }
        Else if (c.controls.Count > 0)
        {
            SetCheckBoxState(c.Controls)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time...in fact that was what i was doing intrinsically in the "GetCheckedAttributes" method.

Comment: Not a problem.. I've done this many times and once you do it enough it becomes almost natural.. Vote up if this solution helps .. have a great evening..